Rebind the MS Teams team to a specific SharePoint site
We've performed a migration of Slack to MS Teams.
One of the tasks was to perform the migration of multiple channels to one logical team.
The migration process was completed successfully.
However, after migration, we discovered that it is not possible to attach files to one channel in the team (later we found more than one such channel).
The fix was to open the tab "Files" in Teams, then the user was allowed to upload (attach) files.
During the troubleshooting, we found that while the migration process is in progress, and there's a need to upload files (found in Slack), an associated SharePoint site is created.
In our case, the SharePoint site with the same name (as the team name itself) was created early (probably during our migration tests/dry runs and wasn't deleted properly) which led to the creation of a SharePoint site with a  different naming (as two SharePoint sites with the same naming couldn't exist) during the real migration.
(examples:
team name = prj-team
existing (early created) ShP site = https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/prj-team
newly created ShP site (bound to an MS Teams team) = https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/prj-team956  )
This implies a lot of inconvenience for the users and we're looking  the way to resolve/mitigate it.
We cannot destroy all teams and channels and restart the migration.
The question here - can a team in MS Teams be updated to be bound to another SharePoint site?
Thanks.
